# select one face detector from multiple faces in image

Tags: python, face-detection

I have already implements face detection in python successfully, the code can detect all faces inside the image.

I have celebrities dataset and after the code return all faces detection ( draw rectangle around all of them) I want to select one of them to be processed in the next step. I follow the bellow code to detect faces.

```
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
image = cv2.imread(im)
rects = detector(image)

for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    (x, y, w, h) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    print("Draw Red rectangle around face")

cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code display image with rectangle around each of the face exist. After I display the image and shows the detector, I want to select one of them. How can I do that, can anyone please help me to select one of them if more than one face exist. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by you want to select one of them, all your faces are already stored in the rects variable

Comment: @shadow thank you for your reply.  due to this is a preprocessing step for face recognition, the following step take the detected face to be processed. This code return only the last face detected, I want specific one of them, but I cannot able to reach it. How can I select one of them from rects variable.

Comment: i guess you are using this tutorial "https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/". and to select one of the bounding box i guess you can just use it like a regular list . rects[n] and 0<= n <len(rects).

Answer (score 0):

you can use it to get the closest face

```
def sorted_faces(faces):
area = lambda x,y,w,h:(w-x)*(h-y)
i = 0
face_dict = {}
l_ = []
if len(faces) > 0:
    for face in faces:
        i+=1
        x = face.left()
        y = face.top()
        w = face.right()
        h = face.bottom()
        my_area =  area(x,y,w,h)
        face_dict[f"{my_area}"] = i

    l_ = [int(i) for i in face_dict.keys()]
    return face_dict[f"{np.array(l_).max()}"]
```

use this code if you want to get the face out of detection

```
x = face.left()
        y = face.top()
        w = face.right()
        h = face.bottom()
        face_image = frame[y:h,x:w]
```